# Properties and setter creating a class in different version of Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want build a class in Python 2.7 (called Point) and check input parameters like coordinates and others attributes. I thought a better way would be making a class with property and setter in each parameter. Like this:

```
class P:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x < 0:
            self.__x = "Negative"
        else:
            self.__x = "Positive"
```

Calling P class with atribute:

```
p1 = P(1001)
print(p1.x)
```

And here is my qestion, I do not understand why in Python 2.7 do not execute the setter but, if you check this code in Python3 editor this run printing "Positive". How can i do this procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without inheriting from `object` in Python 2 you're getting a `classobj`, the old style 'classic' classes, instead of a new style class.

New-style classes, the ones explicitly inheriting from `object` in Python 2, support descriptors. In python 3, this inheritance is implicit.

In short, inherit from `object`.

Comment: Thanks, just defining the class inherit from object works fine.